# iOS Paging Controls (Navigation)

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

Is there a way that I can use those paging dots independently in my app,

add them to my UIView/NIB and call the functions on it to set total number of dots or current page/dot.

Basically I've UIViewImage in a nib file, i'm displaying images (names taken off an array) on swipe gestures and want to show those paging dots on the bottom for the navigation information.

Comment: UIPageControl is the answer... I couldn't find the exact keywords on Google to use to reach the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`UIPageControl` has it's total page & current page/dot just as you described, let's say `pageControl` is a instance of `UIPageControl`, then you can initiate the `numberOfPages` & `currentPage` as below:

```
pageControl.numberOfPages = [images count];
pageControl.currentPage = 0;
```

Also, you can add action for it when the `pageControl`'s dots was tapped. `changePage:` method here is just a example:

```
[pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changePage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

You can add your images to a `UIScrollView` and use its delegate method: `scrollViewDidScroll:`:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    // Update the page number
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    pageControl.currentPage = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
}
```

It'll change the `pageControl`'s current dot when your swiped to a new image.